# An error occurred while making firebase dynamic link. include error code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
 <script>
    var URL = 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=MY_KEY'
    const req = new Request(URL,{
        method : "POST",
        headers : new Headers({
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }),
        context: {
            "longDynamicLink" : "https://MY_DOMAIN.page.link/?link=EXAMPLE_LINK",
            "suffix" : {
                "option" : "SHORT"
            }
        }
    });
var response = fetch(req).then(res=>res.json()).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)));
    </script>
```

I want to make shortlink. My longDynamiclink is working
so I send request, but I received the following response.

> {code: 400
>
> message: "Unsupported dynamic link request
>   DYNAMICLINK_NOT_SET.[https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]"
>
> status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}

Is there a problem with my code? Or did I make the wrong request? Please let me know how I can fix my code to get the correct response.

thanks.

Comment: I would guess there is a good chance its an encoding issue with the long link. Can you check the the EXAMPLE_LINK is URL encoded properly (or try a very simple link to test with)? If you can share more details of specific request, that would help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out first:

1. Make sure that you've already added the SHA1 and SHA256 certificate fingerprint to your Firebase Project Configuration
2. Enable "Firebase Dynamic Links API" for your project at console.cloud.google.com console